# Python cannot import name from some scipy.signal methods

Tags: python, scipy

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
```

The third line triggers the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name find_peaks
```

What is going on here? I haven't made any changes to the scipy package that I am aware of. Also it is worth noting that just importing scipy.signal does not produce an error.

Comment: Replicated. I can't find it either, are you sure this file/module exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your `scipy` version:

```
import scipy
print(scipy.__version__)
```

`find_peaks` is new in version 1.1.0.

If you want to update:

```
pip install scipy --upgrade
```

Comment: I must have asked this question when I was using an older version of Scipy. Now I have 1.2.1, and the code in my post above works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to reinstall scipy and it worked on Mac OS with M1 and Python 3.9

`pip uninstall scipy`

and then

`pip install scipy`

Comment: upgrading scipy worked for me